# g++ compiling: can I link to a directory with symlinked binaries?

Tags: c++, g++, symlink

The below compiles:

`g++ -L../../lib -o my_prog my_prog.cpp -ltest1 -ltest2`

where `../../lib` contains symlinks to libtest1.so and libtest2.so

But I am getting an error when I run the program: "error while loading shared libraries: libtest1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" and am not sure if symlinking is the culprit.

Comment: Symlinks are regularly used with shared objects (e.g. libz.so is generally a symlink to libz.so.1.2.11.whatever), so, if they are valid, they are unlikely to be the culprit.

Comment: What does this have to do with makefiles?

Comment: You can use `ldd` to check the paths to shared objects

Comment: You right about having nothing to do with the Makefile. Updating.

Comment: Have you *really* put libraries `libtest1.so` and `libtest2.so` into `/lib` in
your root filesystem? If not, edit your question to show the actual facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens at *runtime* is related to the [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath).

You may want (not really recommended, see [this](https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html)) to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately before running your executable, or better yet you want to set the executable's rpath when linking it (e.g. by passing `-Wl,--rpath $(realpath ../../lib/)` to the `g++` command doing the link.

Read Drepper's [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper and the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 2):

Option `-L` is for linker `ld` to find `.a` and `.so` during linking.

Option `-Wl,-rpath=` is for the *dynamic linker* ld.so to find `.so` when the application is run. You need to use `-Wl,-rpath=` when a required shared library is not in (standard system) directories specified in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Use `$ORIGIN` *dynamic linker* variable to make rpath relative to the path of your executable:

```
g++ -L../../lib -Wl,-rpath='${ORIGIN}/../../lib' -o my_prog my_prog.cpp -ltest1 -ltest2
```

Be careful to make sure `${ORIGIN}` is **not** expanded by the shell or your makefile (this is why it is in single quotes).

[`${ORIGIN}`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so):

> `$ORIGIN` and rpath
>
> `ld.so` understands the string `$ORIGIN` (or equivalently `${ORIGIN}`) in an rpath specification (`DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH`) to mean the directory containing the application executable. Thus, an application located in somedir/app could be compiled with `gcc -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib'` so that it finds an associated shared library in somedir/lib no matter where somedir is located in the directory hierarchy. This facilitates the creation of "turn-key" applications that do not need to be installed into special directories, but can instead be unpacked into any directory and still find their own shared libraries.

Comment: Ah - so even if compiler knows about those directories, Is till need to modify rpath to have runtime access tot them? Thanks!

Comment: @adamits Added more details for you.